# Как получить текст из тега <p> или <div id="wd_content">?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть текст, который находится в теге

```
<p style="margin: 20px 0px 25px 0px"><a href="/word/wood">wood</a>&ensp;—&ensp;
дерево, и т.д.</p>
```

Как его получить, чтобы было:

```
wood —  дерево, и т.д.
```

Я пытался через

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")['0'].innerHTML;
```

Но ничего не получилось, еще хром на innerHTML жалуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное нужно воспользоваться [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) - позволяет задавать или получать текстовое содержимое элемента и его потомков.

```js
var test = document.getElementsByTagName("p")['0'].textContent;
console.log(test);
```

```html
<p style="margin: 20px 0px 25px 0px"><a href="/word/wood">wood</a>&ensp;—&ensp;
дерево, и т.д.</p>
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое.
Я нашел вопрос, где предлагали так сделать:

var d = document;
var firstSingle = d.querySelector('wd_content');
console.log(firstSingle.textContent); 

но так ошибку выдает, а в вашем случае все отлично. Спасибо большое.